# Porting Chrome app to UWP: How to handle "background page"?

Tags: javascript, uwp, google-chrome-app, windows-10-universal, porting

I have a Chrome app (essentially a Chrome extension with some additional API access and displaying its UI in a separate window) that I'm trying to port to UWP. I have the source code of the Chrome app, but a lot of the work for the app is done in its background page. UWP JS apps don't seem to have the concept of a background page, or equivalents to the Chrome extension/app APIs for interacting with background pages.

Is there some way in a UWP JS app to create the equivalent of a "background page" that runs as long as the app does, loads completely before the app does, does not display UI, and can be accessed from other pages? It needs to be persistent (i.e. not reloading every time the UI pages are navigated) and always-available (i.e. completes loading before other pages load).

Alternatively, if there's a better way to do this (port a Chrome app to Windows devices that cannot run Chrome, and needs to run client-side / cannot be hosted on a server), please suggest the alternative approach.

Comment: There is no such "background page" in UWP app and Chrome extension is totally different from UWP app, why do you want to port it to UWP?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT I want to port it so I can run the app (and it is a Chrome app, not an extension, though the difference is not huge) on Windows devices that aren't able to run Chrome, such as Xbox, Win10 S, maybe IoT or HoloLens, etc.  Given that it's written in JS (without even any native code bindings, though it does call some Chrome-specific APIs that I'll need to replace), I figured the best way was to put it in a JS UWP. But, I need a way to handle the logic that normally lives in, and is accessed through, the background page.

Comment: Do you want to only have JS code in your uwp project? Maybe you can try to create a Windows Runtime component and calling it from JavaScript. See the topic [Windows Runtime components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/) to create a c++/ c#  Windows Runtime component and call it from JS project and the topic [Raising Events in Windows Runtime Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/raising-events-in-windows-runtime-components).

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT Well, the idea is to port the app, rather than writing a clone of it in another language. A lot of the heavy lifting is done in the background page; re-writing it in a .NET language would essentially mean re-writing everything except the UI, including stuff like a custom network protocol (implemented via websockets) and some crypto code (which would probably get faster, but which I trust the original implementation of more than my re-implementation).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a "Service" class that lives as long as the app does and contains "Shared" code that needs to be called from multiple places in the app.
For this, I suggest you look into the Singleton pattern (It is a code smell btw) or better yet, use an IoC container and register that class as "Singleton".

Both approaches will allow you to have one instance of said class that maintains its state for as long as the app is running.

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm trying to port a Chrome app (which is written entirely in JavaScript). Conceptually, the UWP equivalent of a Chrome app/extension's background page is probably the `Application` object, but that doesn't seem to exist for UWPs written in JavaScript! I'm not sure if background services are either, but even if they were, they aren't really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One mostly-working solution that I found by trial and error:

Change the default page of the app (specified in the manifest) to `background.html` (or whatever the background page is called). This ensures that it gets loaded first. Then implement [`chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime#event-onLaunched) as a `window.onload(callback)` or `window.addEventListener('load', callback)` trigger; this will be the entry point for the user-interaction part of the app (where the app displays UI, etc.). There are two more critical code changes that will be needed on every page that does any window management (1) or accesses the background page at all (2); in practice it's best to put them into a JS/TS file that gets included on every page:

1. Modify the window-handling code to create/display full-width-and-height `<iframes>` on the "background page". In practice, this may mean either modifying or "implementing" the [`chrome.app.window`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) APIs, which are not provided by default on UWPs. (You could also change every place that such APIs are used to your own frame-handling functions, but that's probably more work). I just used raw DOM manipulation functions; jquery would work too. Whichever iframe is visible at any given time becomes, in effect, the active window. You may be able to get away with only a partial implementation of the [`AppWindow`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-AppWindow) type, if your app doesn't use all of the functionality of the Chrome API.
2. Implement [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) (or re-write all references to it) to instead walk up the `window.parent` hierarchy to reach the background page, and schedule the callback there. Depending on your app, you may also need to implement other [`chrome.runtime`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime) APIs and/or types.

Overall, I got this approach working pretty well. It enables the use of the "background page" as an app-wide global object, with arbitrary properties and APIs. It ensures that the background page is loaded first and unloaded last (and is able to catch the unload events of content pages, etc.). It even has some perks, such as enabling a pseudo-splash-screen (add an image or similar to the top of the "background" page, where it will display until the JS is done loading and the `onload` event - simulating the `chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched` event - fires). It has some weaknesses too, though:

- Chrome apps support displaying multiple windows at once. UWP apps support this on the desktop, but not elsewhere. You can force there to only be one window (load all different "windows" in whole-window iframes), but then you need to handle switching between them if there's ever a case where the app expects to display two windows at once. You could also do a split-view thing (multiple "window" iframes visible at once) but that's more work to get right.
- Chrome apps support specifying window dimensions. UWP apps have limited support for this on desktop, and none at all on platforms where apps always run full-screen.
- Chrome apps have a bunch of other APIs, such as for file system access and so on, that you may need to replace / re-implement using `Windows.*` APIs. Not all that hard to find them, since the debugger will yell at you for trying to call non-existent functions, but it may make the porting effort bigger than the relatively few code changes given here. On the other hand, apps that store all their data in "web-safe" ways (like local storage, indexedDB, or cookies) will be fine.
- Chrome apps are able to keep running (in the background page, which is invisible) without displaying any UI, either for things like constantly monitoring for updates or playing music, or simply to persist data in memory. UWPs can do this (with limitations), but I haven't found a way to do it *in JavaScript*, so in practice when you close the UI window, the app will exit. This also means you have only a very limited ability to respond to the user closing the "last" UI window.